# Demo Data on source code install Odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How to get the demo data on source code in Odoo9 as the demo data of package installation is not there in source code installation.

Upon selection of the load demo data checkbox it give a internal server error. The console fails on some demo file in sale..

```
ParseError: "decoder jpeg not available" while parsing /home/username/odoo/openerp/addons/base/base_demo.xml:38, near
<record id="user_demo" model="res.users">
            <field name="partner_id" ref="base.partner_demo"/>
            <field name="login">demo</field>
            <field name="password">demo</field>
            <field name="signature">--
Mr Demo</field>
            <field name="company_id" ref="main_company"/>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6,0,[ref('base.group_user'), ref('base.group_partner_manager')])]"/>
            <field name="image" type="base64" file="base/static/img/user_demo-image.jpg"/>
        </record>
```

this is the error i am facing while enabling demo data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following.

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

OR

```
sudo pip install pillow --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all the same if you use package install or source install. **Demo data are only loaded in "demonstration mode".** In order to set a database to the demonstration mode, use corresponding checkbox when you create it:
[image]

Comment: But doing this on package install works but not on source Install

Comment: Please make sure you've installed all the [dependencies of Odoo v9](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/requirements.txt) and a proper version of [wkhtml2pdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html).

Comment: you can see the log when creating database to find out the problem.

Comment: @T.V. can you please take a look

Comment: @afwanwh can you please take a look

Comment: @maharshi I pointed out that it should be caused by missing dependency in a previous comment, I also included link to the dependency list of Odoo 9, which appears to be a `requirements.txt` file. BTW `pillow` is listed in this file on the 5th line and my answer/comment were definitely correct. You could install all the requirements with `pip install -r ./requirements.txt` for good, or check the list and install missing ones. However you waited 3 more days before someone did the guesswork for you and pointed out the exact dependency from the list.

Comment: I like to help people, but I do not like "do my job" type of questions.